# Minimum variability check in R or PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql

My Data-set contains temperature values. I want to preform minimum variability check. I would like to check if 3 successive temperature values do not changed with respect to a per-defined threshold (.05), then replacing them with mean value of last three observations.

Comment: Can you give out more details? What is your data set, a time series?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, the data also includes time and date information (timestamp) but I think preforming based on only values would be more straightforward.

Comment: I think `rollapply` would be pertinent here. You can define a "window" (multiculturally speaking an "apple" or a "penguin") and a function that works on that window. You could check what is happening to the values. This check can be very simple, by checking the order of the values or more sophisticated, by doing some sort of a model.

Comment: How'd you go with this? If you didn't have any luck, maybe it's worth updating the question with sample data, etc, and posting a follow-up comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   WITH A as (
   SELECT ambtemp,
          date_trunc('hour', dt)+
          CASE WHEN date_part('minute', dt) >= 6
          THEN interval '6 minutes'
          ELSE interval '0 minutes'
            END as t
          FROM temm),

              B as(
                  SELECT ambtemp,t,

   max(ambtemp::float(23)) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as max_temp,
   min(ambtemp::float(23)) OVER (PARTITION BY t) as min_temp
        FROM A)

          SELECT *

              FROM B
              WHERE (max_temp - min_temp) <= 0.5
```