# Checking for the minimum variability of a temporal database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datetime, variance

I have a table like this:

```
+------------+------------------+
|temperature |Date_time_of_data |
+------------+------------------+
| 4.5        |9/15/2007 12:12:12|                  
| 4.56       |9/15/2007 12:14:16|
| 4.44       |9/15/2007 12:16:02|
| 4.62       |9/15/2007 12:18:23|
| 4.89       |9/15/2007 12:21:01|
+------------+------------------+
```

The data-set contains more than 1000 records and I want to check for the **minimum variability**.
For every 30 minutes if the variance of temperature doesn't exceed 0.2, I want all the temperature values of that half an hour replaced by NULL.

Comment: You mean 30 min *fixed* (like "12:30-13:00") , or with a sliding window (*every* possible interval of width 30 min)

Comment: no not sliding window, I want it to check for the first 30 min, second one ..

Comment: @f.ashouri The 1st part makes sense. The second part ("replaced with by null") is pretty weird. Shouldn't you be aggregating the information into side-table instead of erasing just some of the information? Or, if you want to erase information, erase it fully by deleting the rows, leaving just a single record in a side-table showing `datetime_from, datetime_to, num_samples, temperature_mean, temperature_stddev` ? The selection of the sample at the 1/2 hourly boundary is going to introduce jitter and remove your ability to smooth out sampling error.

Comment: I want the data that their variance is less than 0.2 not to be involved in my analysis. I think it would be OK if all that records deleted from the table.

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045278/minimum-variability-check-in-r-or-postgresql)

Comment: You don't need to *physically remove* the data. You only need an expression (or view) which only yields the rows that happen to lie in an interval with `max(temp) - min(temp) >= xxx`. With that definition it should be trivial to construct a query. (the sliding window variant would be similar, but a bit more complex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a SELECT to get the start of a period for every record:

```
SELECT temperature,
       Date_time_of_data, 
       date_trunc('hour', Date_time_of_data)+
       CASE WHEN date_part('minute', Date_time_of_data) >= 30
            THEN interval '30 minutes'
            ELSE interval '0 minutes'
       END as start_of_period
FROM your_table
```

It truncates the date to hours (9/15/2007 12:12:12 to 9/15/2007 12:12:00)
and then adds 30 minutes if the date initially had more than 30 minutes.

Next - use start_of_period to group results and get min and max for every group:

```
SELECT temperature,
       Date_time_of_data,
       max(Date_time_of_data) OVER (PARTITION BY start_of_period) as max_temp,
       min(Date_time_of_data) OVER (PARTITION BY start_of_period) as min_temp
FROM (previou_select_here)
```

Next - filter out the records, where the variance is more than 0.2

```
SELECT temperature,
       Date_time_of_data
FROM (previou_select_here)
WHERE (max_temp - min_temp) <=0.2
```

And finally update your table

```
UPDATE your_table
SET temperature = NULL
WHERE Date_time_of_data IN (previous_select_here)
```

You may need to correct some spelling mistakes in this queries, before they work. I havent tested them.
And you can simplify them, if you need to.

P.S. If you need to filter out the data with variance less than 0.2 , you can simply create a VIEW from the third SELECT with

```
 WHERE (max_temp - min_temp) > 0.2
```

And use the VIEW instead of table.

Answer (score 2):

This query should do the job:

```
with intervals as (
    select
        date_trunc('hour', Date_time_of_data) + interval '30 min' * round(date_part('minute', Date_time_of_data) / 30.0) as valid_interval
    from T
    group by 1
    having var_samp(temperature) > 0.2
)
select * from T
where 
    date_trunc('hour', Date_time_of_data) + interval '30 min' * round(date_part('minute', Date_time_of_data) / 30.0) in (select valid_interval from intervals)
```

The inner query (labeled as intervals) returns times when variance is over 0.2 (`having var_samp(temperature) > 0.2`). `date_trunc ...` expression rounds Date_time_of_data to half hour intervals.

The query returns nothing on the provided dataset.

```
create table T (temperature float8, Date_time_of_data timestamp without time zone);
insert into T values 
    (4.5, '2007-9-15 12:12:12'),
    (4.56, '2007-9-15 12:14:16'),
    (4.44, '2007-9-15 12:16:02'),
    (4.62, '2007-9-15 12:18:23'), 
    (4.89, '2007-9-15 12:21:01')
;
```